# Probability - Choosing two numbers from $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ such that the minimum is less than $4$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

Two numbers are selected randomly from the set $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ without replacement one by one. The probability that minimum of the two numbers is less than 4, is?

The correct method to solve this question is to take two cases : one in which both numbers are less than $4$ (${}^3C_2$), and the other in which one is greater than $4$ and one is less than $4$ (${}^3C_1 \times {}^3C_1$)

The solution that I came up with is to take one number from $\{1,2,3\}$ and the other number from the remaining numbers ($ {}^3C_1 \times {}^5C_1$) but my answer is wrong.

Can someone please explain me why my answer is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your answer double-counts selections like $\{1,3\}$. You count the two scenarios above as separate scenarios, even though they produce the same result:

- If you first select $1$ from $\{1,2,3\}$, and then select $3$ from the remaining numbers
- If you first select $3$ from $\{1,2,3\}$, and then select $1$ from the remaining numbers

Answer (score 4):

It's wrong because you counted scenarios when both numbers are less than $4$ twice: once as "first is less than $4$, second arbitrary" and once as "first arbitrary, second less than $4$". In such problems you should always check that you count each scenario exactly once.

For the original problem, I think the simplest solution is to count all possible cases ($C_6^2$) and subtract from it number of cases when both numbers are at least $4$ ($C_3^2$). However, your variant with checking two separate cases also works (and of course gives the same answer).